# How to connect to PC (server) using sockets with Android app (client)?

Tags: java, android, networking, tcp

I have a server set up on my PC (using Hercules), which is listening on a port # and waiting for a connection. I can't get the android app to **receive messages** from the server however on my android emulator (Strangely I can send messages to the server), and I can't do either from my physical android phone.

All the examples I'm finding online involve android devices connecting to each other, like this one: https://www.coderzheaven.com/2017/05/01/client-server-programming-in-android-send-message-to-the-client-and-back/

Would I still be able to connect to a PC by just implementing the client side on my android app? What changes would I have to make otherwise?

Directly copy pasting hasn't worked for me...

(Btw the phone and PC are both connected to the same ethernet network, not wifi if that makes a difference)

Thanks!

edit: Turns out my PC was on a different subnet from my phyiscal android phone, and so changing the PC to be on the same subnet as the phone fixed the problem of my phone not being able to even connect, but now it can connect it seems and send messages to the PC, but again not able to receive messages from the hercules server

edit2: My client code (android app)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


public static final int SERVERPORT = xxxx;
public static final String SERVER_IP = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx"; 

private ClientThread clientThread;
private Thread thread;
private LinearLayout msgList;
private Handler handler;
private int clientTextColor;
private EditText edMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setTitle("Client");
    clientTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    handler = new Handler();
    msgList = findViewById(R.id.msgList);
    edMessage = findViewById(R.id.edMessage);
}

public TextView textView(String message, int color) {
    if (null == message || message.trim().isEmpty()) {
        message = "<Empty Message>";
    }
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextColor(color);
    tv.setText(message + " [" + getTime() + "]");
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
    return tv;
}

public void showMessage(final String message, final int color) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            msgList.addView(textView(message, color));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.connect_server) {
        msgList.removeAllViews();
        showMessage("Connecting to Server...", clientTextColor);
        clientThread = new ClientThread();
        thread = new Thread(clientThread);
        thread.start();
        showMessage("Connected to Server...", clientTextColor);
        return;
    }

    if (view.getId() == R.id.send_data) {
        String clientMessage = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
        showMessage(clientMessage, Color.BLUE);
        if (null != clientThread) {
            clientThread.sendMessage(clientMessage);
        }
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (true) {

                String message = input.readLine();
                
                if (null == message || "Disconnect".contentEquals(message)) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                    message = "Server Disconnected.";
                    showMessage(message, Color.RED);
                    break;
                }
                showMessage("Server: " + message, clientTextColor);
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void sendMessage(final String message) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (null != socket) {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                true);
                        out.println(message);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}

String getTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return sdf.format(new Date());
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (null != clientThread) {
        clientThread.sendMessage("Disconnect");
        clientThread = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `I can't get the android app to receive messages from the server ` The first thing you should have told us if your Android client could connect to your server. Only after a cinnection has been established messages can be exchanged.

Comment: @blackapps I think my android client is connecting to the server. When I click connect to server, the hercules window tells me a client has connected. Additionally, the phone can send messages to the server, but cannot receive messages from the server. However, I think that Hercules IS sending the messages, because under "sent data" it shows the message it sent, it just isn't appearing on my phone.

Comment: How is your protocol? Who is the first sending a message upon connection? Then the other should first listen. Post your Android code so we know where you are talking about.

Comment: @blackapps just made an edit! And I click listen from the hercules server, then I click "connect to server" on my phone which I think is working.

Comment: I did not look at your updated post. Only read your latest comment. There is nothing in that comment that we did not knew already as you had told that. Please tell about protocol instead before we have a look at your code.

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry I'm a little new to all this, can you clarify what you mean by protocol?

Comment: If you're wondering if I'm using TCP/IP, yes that is what I'm doing

Comment: That i told you in my comment where i asked you about your protocol the first time. Answer the questions i asked there.

Comment: @blackapps Oh you meant literally like who sends a message first? It doesn't matter I think, I've tried making the server send the message first and the phone send first, but both times only the messages from the phone send.

Comment: My god.. it matters.. why do think i keep asking? It does not matter what protocolls you tried. I wanna know what the client is supposed to do first in your posted code. And i wanna hear if the server handles accordingly.

Comment: @blackapps Hmm I guess I don't really know, it's just code that I copied from the tutorial link I posted.. From what I can see though nothing happens until connect is clicked, then in onClick() the thread gets started.